# Dúvida sobre Null Byte no Bcrypt PHP

Tags: php, criptografia, hash, null, bcrypt

Bom, fiquei sabendo que o Bcrypt do PHP é vulnerável à Null Byte.

Quais são testes que eu tenho que fazer para ver essa vulnerabilidade, e quais são as consêquencias disso??

Comment: Bem até onde eu sei, ninguém vai inserir um caractere nulo em uma senha, então há muito com o que se preocupar. Se a pessoa usar um caractere nulo na senha, ela estará vulnerável a um "dictionary attack".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Várias funções do PHP são (ou já foram) vulneráveis a bytes nulos, um dos maiores problemas era do `include()`, que o PHP parava ao encontrar o nulo, o que permitia ignorar a extensão do arquivo.

---

No caso do BCrypt (não sei como anda o Argon2i no PHP), ele irá usar a string até encontrar um nulo.

Então:

```
$hash = '$2y$10$/nX1tLiwOsGWL4MhUjfEIOBKLV.Oa/uVy7rxqxih2SeNIkCk8doEW';

echo (int)password_verify("a", $hash);
echo PHP_EOL;

echo (int)password_verify("a\0bcde", $hash);
echo PHP_EOL;

echo (int)password_verify("a\0zzzzz", $hash);
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Todos eles retornam `1`, mesmo que sejam diferente.

---

Isso ocorre porque a hash em questão foi criada com um nulo, de tal forma que:

```
password_hash("a\0 Qualquer Coisa Aqui Será Ignorada", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

Este é o problema do null-byte. Em geral ele não é um grande problema, uma vez que senha deve ser definida usando nulos, até onde eu saiba. Entretanto isso irá burlar o número de caracteres mínimos para uma senha. Porque `a\0 Qualquer Coisa Aqui Será Ignorada` será mais de 10 bytes, por exemplo, mas sua senha terá apenas 1 byte (`a`).

---

A solução disso é fazer um pre-hashing, mas deverá codificar para um formato seguro, afinal o resultado de um SHA-2, por exemplo, pode conter um nulo.

A outra opção talvez seja abandonar o BCrypt, você tem o LibSodium no PHP, creio que estas funções (especificamente o `sodium_crypto_pwhash_str`) não tenha problemas.