# Limite de caracteres do bcrypt no PHP

Tags: php, segurança, hash, bcrypt

Na documentação do PHP referente a função [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php) possui o aviso:

> **Cuidado** Usando **PASSWORD_BCRYPT** como algoritmo, resultará no parâmetro **password** sendo truncado em um comprimento máximo de 72 caracteres.

Ou seja, se eu passar uma senha com mais de 72 caracteres a função desconsiderara os caracteres a mais do final

Na pergunta aqui SOpt [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura), é dito pela melhor resposta sobre o bcrypt:

> Desvantagens:
>
> [...]
>
> - A senha de entrada é limitada a 51 caracteres. Para senhas maiores, alguém teria que combinar o bcrypt com uma função de hash (calcula o hash da senha, e usa o resultado com bcrypt). Combinar primitivos criptográficos tem riscos, então isto não é recomendado para uso geral.

Dúvidas:

- É isso que o PHP usa para aumentar o limite de caracteres?
- Esse limite extra traz algum problema de segurança?
- Ele pode ser desabilitado ou burlado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O limite é de 72 bytes, não de 51. O limite de 51 é errado, ou é uma confusão, ou as implementações recentes não seguem a original. Na verdade, me parece que esse limite tem origem do limite do Blowfish, o Blowfish [é um algoritmo de encriptação onde o tamanho da chave era de 448 bits (56 bytes)](https://www.schneier.com/academic/archives/1994/09/description_of_a_new.html), tal algoritmo é usado pelo BCrypt.

A versão do Bcrypt 2A (e seguintes) exige que o a senha use UTF-8 e que termine um nulo, assim é utilizado 71 caracteres + 1 nulo.

---

> É isso que o PHP usa para aumentar o limite de caracteres?

Não. O PHP usa o Bcrypt normal, inclusive o resultado dele pode ser usado em outras implementações, de outras linguagens.

> Esse limite extra traz algum problema de segurança?

Não, em geral. Nenhum usuário comum utiliza senhas maiores do que 71 caracteres, entretanto seria ideal limitar a entrada do usuário e notifica-lo que a senha é longa.

> Ele pode ser desabilitado ou burlado?

Use outro algoritmo, o PHP já oferece suporte para o Argon2id, que é o vencedor do [PHC](https://password-hashing.net) e em versões antigas já tem suporte para o PBKDF2, que é uma alternativa também, embora não aconselho. Se você está usando alguma versão obsoleta, então segurança não é prioridade.

Se você realmente quer usar gambiarras, existe como, mas também possuem efeitos colaterais.

```
password_hash(base64_encode(hash("sha384", $password, true)), PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

Isso irá fazer com que a entrada do usuário use o `sha384`, primeiro, antes do BCrypt. O BCrypt irá usar o resultado o `sha384` (48 bytes) em Base64 (ficando dentro do limite, usando 64 caracteres). Mas, você irá diminuir a entropia máxima de 71 para 48. A razão de usar o `sha384` é por causa do tamanho, e o [Base64 é para impedir nulos prematuros, porque o BCrypt é vulnerável a nulos, por assim dizer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280442/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-null-byte-no-bcrypt-php).